# Access DB - Indexes start from 0 or 1?

Tags: ms-access

I'm writing a program where I will retrieve some rows and columns from the database.

Does the index of values (columns, rows, cells) in MS Access start from 0 or from 1 because my tables in the client starts from 0 and I need to know how to transfer the data.

Comment: Whenever I am uncertain about whether an index is 0-based or 1-based I just try using 0 as an index, e.g., `myRecordSet(0).Value` and see if I get an "Index out of range" (or similar) message.

Comment: I still don't have a database connected, still working on my client and thought I would save some time asking here and avoid creating a database for testing right now. I need to know how to start my indexes in the client.

Comment: Thank you. If it's no, I've seen that there is a way to make it start from 1 (or from 0 in my situation) right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use DAO or ADO, then the indexes should be 0-based for all of the collections.

If you use the `GetRows` method of the `DAO.Recordset` or the `ADO.Recordset`, the arrays will be 0-based (unlike Excel which uses 1-based arrays), but note that the ADO/DAO `GetRows` arrays are indexed first by field/column, and then by record/row, which is the opposite of an array from a multi-celled-Range's `Value` in Excel.

You can use `Option Base 0` or `Option Base 1` in VBA to force your *own* arrays to default to 0-based or 1-based respectively, but that option will not have any effect on the index-bases of ADO or DAO collections, nor the base of the arrays returned by `GetRows`.